# NavigationDrawer blocks/stops other buttons on the activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I'm creating an app where once you log in, you can click a button and it leads you to a quiz, however, the Profile activity (activity when you first log in) has a navigation drawer and for some reason, the navigation drawer is blocking the use of the buttons on the Profile that leads to the Quiz activity. Does anyone know how to fix this? If there's anything I can do please let me know. I'm sorry if this is a stupid question this is my first time coding an app.

**Profile Java:**

```
package com.example.civis;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
private DrawerLayout drawer;
private Button quizbutton;
private Button enrolbutton1;


//Menu Drawer Set Up
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    quizbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quizbutton);
    quizbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openQuiz();
        }
    });


    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    }


// Menu Drawer Navigation
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
    switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.nav_profile:  // Profile Page Link
            Intent i = new Intent(Profile.this, Profile.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_current_mps:  // Current MP's Link
            Intent mpi = new Intent(Profile.this, CurrentMps.class);
            startActivity(mpi);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_local_board:  // Local Board Link
            Intent locali = new Intent(Profile.this, LocalBoard.class);
            startActivity(locali);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_referendums:  // Referendums Link
            Intent referendumi = new Intent(Profile.this, Referendums.class);
            startActivity(referendumi);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_elections:    // Elections Link
            Intent electioni = new Intent(Profile.this, Election.class);
            startActivity(electioni);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_about_us:     // About Us Link
            Intent aboutusi = new Intent(Profile.this, AboutUs.class);
            startActivity(aboutusi);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_settings:     // Settings Link
            Intent settingsi = new Intent(Profile.this, Settings.class);
            startActivity(settingsi);
            break;
        case R.id.nav_signout:      // Sign Out Link (Links to Sign In Page)
            Intent signouti = new Intent(Profile.this, SignIn.class);
            startActivity(signouti);
            break;
    }

    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

public void openQuiz() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, quiz1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

**Profile XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".Profile"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<!-- White Card Style Backing -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="550dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="195dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle_white" />

<!-- Profile Person Image -->
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:src="@drawable/dp_civis"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<!-- Name Area -->
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:background="@drawable/edit_text_style"
    android:text="Name"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="24sp" />

<!-- Political Compass Quiz Button -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/quizbutton"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="160dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_purple_button_style"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Political Compass Quiz"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Enrol to Vote Button -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:visibility="visible">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/enrolbutton1"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:background="@drawable/edit_purple_button_style"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Enrol to Vote"
        android:textColor="#FFF"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- Menu Drawer-->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**Quiz Java:**

```
package com.example.civis;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Random;

public class quiz1 extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView countLabel;
private TextView questionLabel;
private Button answerBtnAgree;
private Button answerBtnDisagree;
private String rightAnswer;
private int rightAnswerCount = 0;
private int quizCount = 1;
static final private int QUIZ_COUNT =5;

ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> quizArray = new ArrayList<>();

String quizData[][] = {
        // {Question, Choice 1, Choice 2}
        {"All firearms should be registered and it should be tougher to get a licence.", "Agree", "Disagree"},
        {"16-year-olds are mature enough to make informed decisions so they should be allowed to vote.", "Agree", "Disagree"},
        {"It should be compulsory for everyone in New Zealand to be vaccinated against communicable diseases.", "Agree", "Disagree"},
        {"We expect too much of NZ’s Police, and some of their work should be done by communities, mental health experts, and social services.", "Agree", "Disagree"},
        {"New Zealand’s borders should remain closed to non-citizens until a COVID-19 vaccine is found, even if that takes years.", "Agree", "Disagree"},
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz1);

    countLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.countLabel);
    questionLabel = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.questionLabel);
    answerBtnAgree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerBtnAgree);
    answerBtnDisagree = (Button)findViewById(R.id.answerBtnDisagree);

    // Create quizArray from quizDara

    for (int i = 0; i < quizData.length; i++) {

        // Prepare array.
        ArrayList<String> tmpArray = new ArrayList<>();
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][0]); // Question
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][1]); // Agree
        tmpArray.add(quizData[i][2]); // Disagree

        // Add tmpArray to quizArray.
        quizArray.add(tmpArray);
    }

    showNextQuiz();

}

public void showNextQuiz() {

    // Update quizCountLabel.
    countLabel.setText("Q" + quizCount);

    // Generate random number between 0 and 1 (quizArray's size -1 )
    Random random = new Random();
    int randomNum = random.nextInt(quizArray.size());

    // Pick one quiz set.
    ArrayList<String> quiz = quizArray.get(randomNum);

    // Set question and right answer.
    // Array format:             // {Question, Choice 1, Choice 2,}
    questionLabel.setText(quiz.get(0));
    rightAnswer = quiz.get(1);

    // Remove "Question" from quiz and Shuffle choices
    quiz.remove(0);

    // Set Choices.
    answerBtnAgree.setText(quiz.get(0));
    answerBtnDisagree.setText(quiz.get(1));

    // Remove this quiz from quizArray.
    quizArray.remove(randomNum);

}

public void checkAnswer(View view) {

    // Get pushed button.
    Button answerBtn = (Button) findViewById(view.getId());
    String btnText = answerBtn.getText().toString();

    String alertTitle;

    if(btnText.equals(rightAnswer)) {

        alertTitle = "Thank you for responding";
        rightAnswerCount++;

    } else {

        alertTitle = "Thank you for responding";
    }
    // Create Dialogue
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle(alertTitle);
    builder.setMessage("Your response has been recorded");
    builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            if (quizCount == QUIZ_COUNT) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ResultActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("RIGHT_ANSWER_COUNT", rightAnswerCount);
                startActivity(intent);

            } else {
                quizCount++;
                showNextQuiz();;
            }
        }
    });
    builder.setCancelable(false);
    builder.show();



}
```

}

**Quiz XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".quiz1"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_background">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/countLabel"
    android:text="Q1"
    android:textSize="28dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_marginTop="120dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionLabel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Question"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_light"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/answerBtnAgree"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
    android:text="Agree"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:onClick="checkAnswer"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/answerBtnDisagree"
    android:layout_width="320dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:text="Disagree"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
    android:onClick="checkAnswer"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DrawerLayout` should be the parent if you're using `NavigationView`.
Put the `RelativeLayout` inside the `DrawerLayout`.

Your xml should look something like this:

```
<!-- Menu Drawer-->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

    <!-- OTHER VIEWS -->

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```